# How to get multiple sentence in a line in a string column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below Dataframe. I need to remove the space between two sentence, and have it in one.

Input :

```
id  text
1   compliant solve.
    today  query clear
2   branch visit on date-16/02/2018
    contact person
    xyz -101010101
3   visit on date-16/06/2018
    contact person-ddd -66666
4   visit on date-14-02-2018
    contact person
    ak -80000003
```

Output from dataframe using to_dict :

```
140: 'visit on date-16/02/2018\ncontect person\xyz-567890',
141: 'visit on date-08/02/2018\ncontect person \nabc - 908789\nabcd
142: 'visit on date-08/03/2018\ncontect person\npqrspqrs pqrssssp -8909787901',
143: 'visit on date-08/05/2018\ncontect person-jagggan aaaa 897654321',
144: 'visit on date-09/02/2018\ncontect person\nqqqqqqqqqe-9087654321',
145: 'abcdefgh\n business sourcing\n35000 sourced',
```

Output from df:

```
369: 'abcdefgh. \n\ndiscussion on xyz', 370: 'new byusiness', 371: 'new 
busnes', 372: 'ghi call', 373: 'new business\npolicy deliver\npaopo refund'
```

Output :

```
id  text
1   compliant solve. today  query clear
2   branch visit on date-16/02/2018 contact person xyz -101010101
3   visit on date-16/06/2018 contact person-ddd -66666
4   visit on date-14-02-2018 contact person ak -80000003
```

Comment: Use `df.groupby('id')['text'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: @jezrael: Are you sure?  I assumed there were actual newlines in the values.  Otherwise, would it really display with the repeated index values elided (MultiIndex style, despite there being no obvious MultiIndex)?

Comment: @jezrael : i need to make it into a single sentence within the same row. The question you have linked to is grouping 2 rows. I need it within the same record

Comment: @Anagha - Yes, I find it does not work, so reopened and added solution.

Comment: Can you output your input dataframe using to_dict() and add to the question.

Comment: @ScottBoston : I have updated it. However i tried replacing "\n" with blank. But it did not change anything

Comment: Hrm.. try this print(df.head(10).to_dict()) copy and paste that to the question.  I would like to see the full dataframe structure with 10 records of data.

Comment: Its a huge amount of data. And the sentences like these are in somewhere random. Also the data is pretty confidential. However I have uploaded a sample in the question, please have a look at it

Comment: John Zwinck's solution works, you have another problem.  To help, show your input data, your code, and your out you are getting from that code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.text = df.text.str.replace('\n', ' ')
```